# UIView won't recognize a subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I need to create a UIView with a UILabel subview programmatically because it works better than IB for animations.  I cannot get the UIView to recognize the UILabel though.  Here is my code from viewDidLoad:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(764, 94, 200, 100)];
[label setText:@"Hello"];
[label setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

UIView *hintView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(764, 94, 240, 198)];
[hintView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(34/255.f) green:(59/255.f) blue:(27/255.f) alpha:(255/255.f)]];

[hintView addSubview:label];
[self.view addSubview:hintView];

NSLog(@"subview %@", hintView.subviews);
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that your log doesn't show the label? I copied and pasted you code, and it worked for me.

Comment: I am having small doubt in your question is label not appearing on the view

Comment: "I need to create a UIView with a UILabel subview programmatically because it works better than IB for animations." Be careful with comments like this, they're very subjective and probably irrelevant. It even makes me suspect one or two things: You also have a lot of absolute hardcoded points and sizes, which often makes for brittle work. Anyone supporting iPhone 5 having relied on the iPhone 4 screen size, or anyone having to support landscape after relying on being portrait-only, or anyone who has ever developed for Android, can tell you of their pain. Try to make relative statements.

Comment: it seems that your creating the label just outside the hintView's x value view. try setting the first parameter of the label's frame within 0-763. Not so sure if this will fix the issue but the label shouldnt be shown in the hintview if this current code is executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(764, 94, 200, 100)];
```

You are setting wide frame try this

```
 UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100)];
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `yourLable.frame.origin.x` between **`(0) to (320 - withOfYourLabel)`**

Above code is same for your custom `UIView` *(set `X`)*

And if you want to get subViews of your custom view then follow

```
for(UIView *subView in hintViewsubviews)
{
     /// here you got all subview of hintView

     if([subView isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
     {
            // here you can also check that subView is UILabel or not ?
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are taking same frame size for  both UIView and Label.bcz of that you are not getting proper output.See the changes which i have done to you code and try this

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(hintView.frame.origin.x+15, hintView.frame.origin.y+50, hintView.frame.size.width-60, hintView.frame.size.height-100)];
[label setText:@"Hello"];
[label setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

UIView *hintView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(764, 94, 240, 198)];
[hintView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(34/255.f) green:(59/255.f)    blue:(27/255.f) alpha:(255/255.f)]];

[hintView addSubview:label];
[self.view addSubview:hintView];

NSLog(@"subview %@", hintView.subviews);
```

Comment: This will give compile time errors as you are using `hintView`(line1) before it is declared(line5). Also, subview coordinate system starts from (0,0) when added in the superview. So you need to say `UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15,50, hintView.frame.size.width-60, hintView.frame.size.height-100)];`.